# BuffredReader in android is not reading the whole httpResponse

Tags: android, httpresponse, bufferedreader

hi I have the specific url(Given) which is called and gives out put in browser properly but while I use it in android it doesn't provide full output it is just providing partial output

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.livedatatunnel.com/httpsymbolhelper/default.aspx");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        InputStream in=urlConnection.getInputStream();
        urlConnection.connect();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in),2500);
        String result="", line="";

        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            result+=line;
        }

        urlConnection.disconnect();
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

please help...

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a [connect time out](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) and/or a [reading time out](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29).

Comment: On your browser, try to use Android user agent, just to see if the server behaves differently.